# How to make a fixed header with same background as banner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

I'm currently working on my portfolio website, and without the fixed header it looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
<header class="container">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT ME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="heading container">
    <h1 class="wow animated bounceInDown">SAKIR INTESER</h1>
    <h4 class="wow animated bounceInUp">FRONT-END WEB DEVELOPER</h4>
</div> <!-- heading -->
```

CSS:

```
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }

nav{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
} 

nav ul li{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.logo{
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

/**************banner************/ 

.banner {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 60% 0%;
}
```

Now I want to make it a fixed/sticky header and it's creating some troubles. Basically, I want the header to function like this: http://codepen.io/benthom21/full/GNqwXd/
scroll down there to see what I'm talking about, notice that the header is within the banner image,  but that is in bootstrap, and I want to have it in plain html, css and jQuery. I tried to achieve this with the following code, but it did'nt work, the html part is,

```
<div class="banner">
<header class="container">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT ME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="heading container">
    <h1 class="wow animated bounceInDown">SAKIR INTESER</h1>
    <h4 class="wow animated bounceInUp">FRONT-END WEB DEVELOPER</h4>
</div> <!-- heading -->
```

the css is:

```
    header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: pink;
}
nav{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
} 

nav ul li{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.logo{
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

/**************banner************/ 

.banner {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 60% 0%;
}
```

[and it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq1QP.png)

the banner is really messed up here, the text is not seen and the header is not centered. Any kind of help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
p{
    height: 1024px;
}
 header{
    margin:0;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
.add-background{
    background-color:rgba(22, 0, 22, 0.5);
}
.banner img {
    width:100%;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
You can place anything in this header content. In your case it is the place for menu.
</header>
<div class="banner"><img src="https://placehold.it/800x300"></div>
<p>
Add more content here so that you can sroll the page
</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
        header = $('.header');

    if (scrollPos > 40) {
      header.addClass('add-background');
    } else {
      header.removeClass('add-background');
    }
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

I have made simple page to show you the example of jquery code which dynamically changes the class of header when user scrolls the page. Use css code to make the background transparent from default. Then use jquery to add background. Hope you will get the idea.

Comment: You're welcome and don't forget to Up Vote also, If it's the best answer...

Comment: I would've but my reputation is still less than 15, so I can't upvote it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-model: border-box;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    }

.nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;  
    height: 80px; 
    background-color: #000; 
    z-index: 1
} 

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100px;       
    line-height: 80px;    
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: right;
    
    }
    .nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 80px;       
    line-height: 80px;   
    text-decoration: none;
    }

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    height: 80px;
    float: left; 
}

/**************banner************/ 

.banner {
    height: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 60% 0%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="banner">
     <div class ="nav">
         <ul>
         <!--push a logo down to <ul> section -->
          <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="http://blackheatbuilders.ctow.review/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/example-logo.png" height="80px"></a>
             <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
             <li><a href="#about">ABOUT ME</a></li>
             <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
             <li><a href="#photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
             <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
<div class="heading container">
    <h1 class="wow animated bounceInDown">SAKIR INTESER</h1>
    <h4 class="wow animated bounceInUp">FRONT-END WEB DEVELOPER</h4>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```